# Make [huffman] a synonym of [huffman-encoding]; possibly rename to [huffman-coding]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

[huffman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huffman) and [huffman-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huffman-encoding) are both about [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).  They should be merged, or even renamed to "huffman-coding".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Merged into [huffman-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huffman-coding).

Comment: Bah, I knew I should have commented as soon as I saw this post.  "Huffman Coding" is a good tag for math.SE, as it is an area of theoretical mathematics.  Here we deal with source code for finding, compressing, and decompressing using Huffman codes... those algorithms are "Huffman encoders" (and decoders), and the process is "Huffman encoding".  So [tag:huffman-encoding] should have stayed the primary tag.